# Selecting Grand Child of Parent - Returning VAR as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table, the features of this table is:

1. A list of users
2. Once a user clicks the invite span it runs a uniquely generated piece of JS.
3. The table has a select checkbox on each row

What am I trying to Achieve:

1. Build a select all checkbox - Working
2. Once a user clicks an add all button, it must simulate a click on the button on each span for the invite in the same row as the so the relevant js can be run.

I can however not get the add all to work. Here is the code.

**The HTML**

```
<table aria-describedby="usersslavetoinvitestable_info" class="dataTable no-footer" id="usersslavetoinvitestable" role="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" /></th>
            <th aria-controls="usersslavetoinvitestable" aria-label="User ID: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending" class="sorting_asc" colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 0px;" tabindex="0">User ID</th>
            <th aria-controls="usersslavetoinvitestable" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending" class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 0px;" tabindex="0">Name</th>
            <th aria-controls="usersslavetoinvitestable" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column ascending" class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 0px;" tabindex="0">ID</th>
            <th aria-controls="usersslavetoinvitestable" aria-label="Client Type: activate to sort column ascending" class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 0px;" tabindex="0">Client Type</th>
            <th aria-controls="usersslavetoinvitestable" aria-label="Invite: activate to sort column ascending" class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 0px;" tabindex="0">Invite</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="userinvitehide208 odd" role="row">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="user" name="checkbox-208" id="checkbox-208" /></td>
      <td class="sorting_1">208</td>
            <td>Tester Johnson</td>
            <td>7903225038799</td>
            <td>Investor <span class="multisep">|</span> Golfer <span class="multisep">|</span></td>
            <td class="invite"><span class="invitebutton" id="uid208">Invite Now</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="userinvitehide221 even" role="row">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="user" name="checkbox-221" id="checkbox-221" /></td>
            <td class="sorting_1">221</td>
            <td>Ruan Pienaar</td>
            <td>8305215038988</td>
            <td>Private Wealth <span class="multisep">|</span> Cyclist <span class="multisep">|</span></td>
            <td class="invite"><span id="uid221">Invite Now</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="userinvitehide224 odd" role="row">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="user" name="checkbox-224" id="checkbox-224" /></td>
            <td class="sorting_1">224</td>
            <td>Kyle Warmback</td>
            <td>7983224869044</td>
            <td>Golfer <span class="multisep">|</span></td>
            <td class="invite"><span class="invitebutton" id="uid224">Invite Now</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="userinvitehide225 even" role="row">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="user" name="checkbox-225" id="checkbox-225" /></td>
            <td class="sorting_1">225</td>
            <td>Gardiol Lamberts</td>
            <td>8403226038944</td>
            <td>Private Wealth <span class="multisep">|</span> Cyclist <span class="multisep">|</span></td>
            <td class="invite"><span class="invitebutton" id="uid225">Invite Now</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="userinvitehide226 odd" role="row">      
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="user" name="checkbox-226" id="checkbox-226" /></td>
            <td class="sorting_1">226</td>
            <td>Ulof Van Der Westhuizen</td>
            <td>8704223949733</td>
            <td>Investor <span class="multisep">|</span> Cyclist <span class="multisep">|</span></td>
            <td class="invite"><span class="invitebutton" id="uid226">Invite Now</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<!-- select all boxes -->

<button id="add-all">Add Selected</button>
```

**The JS for the checbox toggle all - Working**

```
// Listen for click on toggle checkbox
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
    if(this.checked) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;                        
        });
    } else {
    // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;                        
        });
    }
});
```

**The add selected button function as I have it right now**

This is not working, the child is not identifying.

```
$('#add-all').click(function(){
        $('.user:checked').each(function () {
    //Log Execute
    console.log('Executed user call');
    //Identify Parent
    var trclass = $(this).parent().parent().attr('class');
    console.log('trclass is ' + trclass);
    //spanid
    var spanid = $(trclass).find('td.invite').find('td.invitebutton').find('span').attr('class');
    console.log('spanid is ' + spanid);
    //Click Button

    })
});
```

Here is the JS Fiddle I am working on:
https://jsfiddle.net/Webvelopment/ob1hd3rw/8/#&togetherjs=zMcgQU9zo4

I really can't figure out why it is not identifying. I also dont know how to simulate a click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simulate a click, you can simply call `.click()` on the target element.

As for the rest, you could just replace that whole function body with `$('tr').has('.user:checked').find('.invitebutton').click();`:

`$('tr').has('.user:checked')` -- find all `tr`s that contain a checked `.user` element

`.find('.invitebutton')` -- in those rows, find elements with the class `invitebutton`

`.click();` click the elements

#### [Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob1hd3rw/10/)

```js
// Listen for click on toggle checkbox
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
    if(this.checked) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;                        
        });
    } else {
    // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;                        
        });
    }
});

$('#add-all').click(function(){ 
    $('tr').has('.user:checked').find('.invitebutton').click(); 
});

// just to show it works...
$(document).on('click','.invitebutton',function(){
 console.log('clicked');
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table aria-describedby="usersslavetoinvitestable_info" class="dataTable no-footer" id="usersslavetoinvitestable" role="grid">
 <thead>
  <tr role="row">
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" /></th>
   <th aria-controls="usersslavetoinvitestable" aria-label="User ID: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending" class="sorting_asc" colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 0px;" tabindex="0">User ID</th>
   <th aria-controls="usersslavetoinvitestable" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending" class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 0px;" tabindex="0">Name</th>
   <th aria-controls="usersslavetoinvitestable" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column ascending" class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 0px;" tabindex="0">ID</th>
   <th aria-controls="usersslavetoinvitestable" aria-label="Client Type: activate to sort column ascending" class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 0px;" tabindex="0">Client Type</th>
   <th aria-controls="usersslavetoinvitestable" aria-label="Invite: activate to sort column ascending" class="sorting" colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 0px;" tabindex="0">Invite</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="userinvitehide208 odd" role="row">
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="user" name="checkbox-208" id="checkbox-208" /></td>
      <td class="sorting_1">208</td>
   <td>Tester Johnson</td>
   <td>7903225038799</td>
   <td>Investor <span class="multisep">|</span> Golfer <span class="multisep">|</span></td>
   <td class="invite"><span class="invitebutton" id="uid208">Invite Now</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="userinvitehide221 even" role="row">
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="user" name="checkbox-221" id="checkbox-221" /></td>
   <td class="sorting_1">221</td>
   <td>Ruan Pienaar</td>
   <td>8305215038988</td>
   <td>Private Wealth <span class="multisep">|</span> Cyclist <span class="multisep">|</span></td>
   <td class="invite"><span id="uid221">Invite Now</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="userinvitehide224 odd" role="row">
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="user" name="checkbox-224" id="checkbox-224" /></td>
   <td class="sorting_1">224</td>
   <td>Kyle Warmback</td>
   <td>7983224869044</td>
   <td>Golfer <span class="multisep">|</span></td>
   <td class="invite"><span class="invitebutton" id="uid224">Invite Now</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="userinvitehide225 even" role="row">
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="user" name="checkbox-225" id="checkbox-225" /></td>
   <td class="sorting_1">225</td>
   <td>Gardiol Lamberts</td>
   <td>8403226038944</td>
   <td>Private Wealth <span class="multisep">|</span> Cyclist <span class="multisep">|</span></td>
   <td class="invite"><span class="invitebutton" id="uid225">Invite Now</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="userinvitehide226 odd" role="row">      
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="user" name="checkbox-226" id="checkbox-226" /></td>
   <td class="sorting_1">226</td>
   <td>Ulof Van Der Westhuizen</td>
   <td>8704223949733</td>
   <td>Investor <span class="multisep">|</span> Cyclist <span class="multisep">|</span></td>
   <td class="invite"><span class="invitebutton" id="uid226">Invite Now</span></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<!-- select all boxes -->

<button id="add-all">Add Selected</button>
```